# Phase Portrait of One Dimensional ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, bifurcation

I am very confused... In a homework task I was asked to draw a phase portrait of the following ODE;
$$\dot{x}=\lambda+x^2$$
I have looked into it online and all the problems I have seen deal with a system of ODEs which you can then turn into a matrix and so on...So far I have determined the critical points of this function, namely;
$$x=\pm\lambda i$$
I have also determined their stability. I have also graphed a bifurcation diagram of this. Would a phase portrait of this ODE simply be vectors converging to the stable solutions and for unstable solutions, arrows will be diverging? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is x a real or a complex variable?

Comment: Is it $\dot x = λ^2+x^2$ or did you miss the square root in the second formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are facing with real valued ODE.
Therefore, the steady states are those **real** numbers such that $\dot{x} = 0$.
In your case, you get that:

$$\dot{x} = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda + x^2 = 0 \Rightarrow x = \pm \sqrt{-\lambda}.$$

Of course, if $\lambda < 0$, then you don't have any steady state, as $\pm \sqrt{-\lambda}$ are not real numbers. On the other hand, if $\lambda \geq 0$, then  $x = \pm \sqrt{-\lambda}$ are real and hence they can be considered as steady states. In particular, for $\lambda = 0$, then there is only one steady state $x=0$.

Regarding the phase portrait, I hope this figure can help you.

[image]

The observed phenomenon is also known as "saddle-node" bifurcation.

Comment: So on the bifurcation diagram. how would you then represent the cases for when $\lambda<0$? Also, thank you for your help!

Comment: For $\lambda < 0$, the bifurcation diagram has no steady state. For $\lambda = 0$, it has one metastable steady state. For $\lambda > 0$, there are two steady states, one unstable $x = +\sqrt{-\lambda}$, and one stable $x = -\sqrt{-\lambda}$.